# Changing drawing priority for selected feature in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, topology, select, order

I've noticed that the drawing priority of a selection, is lower than other records in the same table. That is - my record selection gets covered or hidden by unselected records.

I haven't noticed this before and maybe it's a default setting with QGIS 3.16.3.

Does anyone know if there is a setting to change the drawing priority of map selection items?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can change drawing order for the selected features using [Symbology tab](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#symbology-properties) in [Layer Properties](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#the-vector-properties-dialog).

1. Open Symbology tab in Layer Properties or Layer Styling (<kbd>F7</kbd>).
2. Check [`Control feature rendering order`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#layer-rendering).
3. Open `Define Order` window.
4. Type [`is_selected()`](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/expressions/functions_list.html#is-selected) as expression.

[image]

Comment: Thats great, thanks for that. Has QGIS always been like that? Im surprised i haven't come across this before.